# redirect after login with auth0 custom UI using facebook authentication

Tags: facebook, angular, auth0

I am trying to use Auth0 for authorization on my site. I have a log in with facebook button which uses facebook to authorize and it works but I can't get it to go to the new page after it authenticates the user. Here is my code:

```
 private auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
    domain: myConfig.domain,
    clientID: myConfig.clientID,
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200',
    responseType: 'token id_token'
  });

 auth0.authorize({
   connection: 'facebook',
 });
```

Everything works fine except it stays on the same url. I can manually enter the new url and it works fine so the authentication works fine but how can I make it reditect on its own?

Comment: Can you offer more information - what version of Auth0 libraries are you using? Where is your code for storing the tokens after authentication.

Comment: I new to Auth0 but as I understand it, the redirect URL and where the return request comes to, there you can perform what ever action you want, such as saving the token as a cookie, then you should perform the redirect to whatever page you want /home /my-account etc...